# jQuery Form Validation Plugin : Return false on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, plugins

After going through a tutorial on how make jQuery plugins, I decided to give it a shot and make a form validation plugin. I've so far managed to achieve 90% of what I was hoping for and the only thing remaining is making the form to return false if there are empty fields found.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tHMMj/8/)

I've put my whole code at jsfiddle, but it doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps because I need to include my plugin file instead of pasting it in the script section. But I'm sharing it just in case you need to look at the whole code.

#### PLUGIN WORKFLOW

```
(function(jQuery) {
    window.cnt = 0;

    jQuery.fn.border = function() {

       this.each(function() {
        var ele = jQuery(this);
        var cur_val, ele_name;
        if(// element is input, select, or textarea)
        {
           cur_val = ele.val();
        }
        else if(// element is radio)
        {
           ele_name = ele.attr('name');
           cur_val = $('input:radio[name="'+ele_name+'"]:checked').val();
        }
        else if(// element is checkbox)
        {
           ele_name = ele.attr('name');
          cur_val = $('input:checkbox[name="'+ele_name+'"]:checked').val();
        }

        if(! cur_val) // need to do something here to prevent form submission
        {
            cnt++;
            if(// input, textarea, select element)
            {
               ele.addClass('border');
            }
            else if(// radio or checkbox element)
            {
               ele.parent().addClass('border');
            }               
        }
        else // need to do something here to make the form submission happen
        {               
            if(// input, select, textarea)
            {
                ele.removeClass('border');
            }
            else if(radio or checkbox)
            {
                ele.parent().removeClass('border');
            }
        }

        });         
        return this;            
    };
})(jQuery);// JavaScript Document
```

#### WHAT I TRIED

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
            $('.required').border();
            if(window.cnt > 0)
            {               
                return false;
            }
            else
            {               
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I created a global variable `cnt` and tried using it inside the form submission function. It worked when there were empty elements, but it returned `false` even after all elements where filled up. After alerting the value of `cnt`, I found out that on each button click the value of `cnt` kept appending from its previous values and so `cnt > 0` always returned `true`.

Thus, I'm trying to find a way to return `false` from within the plugin function itself so that I won't have to add the `if-else` condition after calling the plugin function.

In a nutshell what I'm trying to achieve is

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('.required').border(); // this line should take care of returning true or false for the submit function           
    });
});
```

Thus, the user should just call `$('.required').border();` and it should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the way I'm using the `valid` variable in the code below, instead of `window.cnt`.

```
jQuery.fn.border = function() {

   var valid = true;

   this.each(function() {
    var ele = jQuery(this);
    var cur_val, ele_name;
    if(// element is input, select, or textarea)
    {
       cur_val = ele.val();
    }
    else if(// element is radio)
    {
       ele_name = ele.attr('name');
       cur_val = $('input:radio[name="'+ele_name+'"]:checked').val();
    }
    else if(// element is checkbox)
    {
       ele_name = ele.attr('name');
      cur_val = $('input:checkbox[name="'+ele_name+'"]:checked').val();
    }

    if(! cur_val) // need to do something here to prevent form submission
    {
        valid = false;
        if(// input, textarea, select element)
        {
           ele.addClass('border');
        }
        else if(// radio or checkbox element)
        {
           ele.parent().addClass('border');
        }               
    }
    else // need to do something here to make the form submission happen
    {               
        if(// input, select, textarea)
        {
            ele.removeClass('border');
        }
        else if(radio or checkbox)
        {
            ele.parent().removeClass('border');
        }
    }

    });
    return valid;       
}
```

Comment: It still submits the form. I can see for a split second that border is being applied. So `valid` becomes `false`, but the form still gets submitted

Comment: When using it in the `submit()` handler, you need to do `return $(".required").border();`

Comment: Actually, that should be: `return $(".required", $(this)).border();`. Otherwise, submitting one form will try to validate all forms on the page.

Comment: Yep. Tried that too. It works fine if fields are empty. But when all fields are filled up, the border is removed from those elements; however the form does not get submitted in this case

Comment: I also tried this to see what is being returned : `var abc = $('.required, $(this)).border(); alert(abc);` The strange thing is I'm shown `true` in the alert box when all fields are filled up, but yet the form does not get submitted.

Comment: Since Javascript operates in the browser, it shouldn't matter where it's hosted. I suspect you made a transcription error.

Comment: +1 I copy pasted the code from you jsfiddle and now it works. Perhaps there was some syntactical or logical error. Anyways thanks. It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to reset the cnt variable when u call the $.border function?

Comment: You mean make `cnt = 0` in the else part?

Comment: He means set it to 0 at the beginning of the jQuery.fn.border function.